# Motion sensor does not detect motion unless "shaken"

Tags: sensor

I have the following hardware:

- Raspberry Pi 2
- Motion sensor ([http://www.amazon.com/Great-Deal-HC-SR501-Infrared-Raspberry/dp/B00M1H7KBW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00M1H7KBW))
- Female to female wires

And followed the tutorial here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/parent-detector/worksheet/

However, the motion sensor doesn't work as expected, even after adjusting the sensitivity and detection time components on the side of the sensor bulb. The behavior of the sensor is such that, it does not detect motion even a few inches in front of it after running pirtest.py script (do not see the "GPIO pin 4 is HIGH", or LOW messages). These messages only happen if I shake the motion sensor bulb itself, which is very odd. I've swapped in other bulbs to see if it's an issue with the bulb, but apparently not. Does anyone have idea why this is happening and how to fix?

Comment: It's not a motion sensor.  It detects the heat given off by humans.  Are you sure you haven't altered the pots to silly values?  It should alarm (go high) when a body is close and stay in the alarm state (high) for 30 seconds or so before it resets to alarm off (low).

Comment: It may be a personal opinion but I'd be wary about including a links that is likely to rot (so that later there is no way to find what the original link was to) however this does seem to be a mass-produced product (lots of Far-Eastern clones, undercutting local retailers) so it may be better to just refer to the part number HC-SR501 and let others look for it if there is not an image you can legitimately include - I found [this](http://www.elecfreaks.com/wiki/index.php?title=PIR_Motion_Sensor_Module:DYP-ME003) article on the ElecFreaks Wiki which had an image and covers this sensor in detail.

Comment: @joan - i'm not sure about the orange knobs' settings (if that's what you mean by "pots")...i know i've tried it at both "extremes" and the behavior is the same. i'll try fiddling with it again tonight.

Comment: @slysven - good idea - i'll add the model numbers.

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto count the knob turns and try to put each back into a central position (assuming that will be close to the default value).  Leave a program running which prints the level every second.  Stay still.  Do the values change?  Move. Do the values change?

Comment: @joan <hairsplitting>Usually PIRs are both, but *moving* IR emitters are *easier to detect* / *can be sensed from a greater distance* than static ones...</hairsplitting> 8-)